# Копирование в VS Code css стилей из html файла вставка в css

Tags: css3, html5, visual-studio-code

При написании кода в формате html 5 - css 3 в редакторе кода VS Code есть возможность скопировать класс/классы (насколько мне известно можно сразу несколько) в html файле и скопировать в файл css, но при этом вставлен он будет в формате css файла. То есть, в html файле я выделяю следующие строки:

```html
<div class="conteiner">
        <div class="row-space-between">
            <a href="#" class="pagination-btn">Предыдущий</a>
            <a href="#" class="pagination-btn">Следующий</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Копируя в css файл я получаю

```css
.conteiner{

}

.row-space-between{

}

.pagination-btn{

}
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

- Установить Class Extractor - расширение для VSCode;
- Выделить HTML;
- Ctrl+Shift+P (или View -> Command Palette...);
- Выполнить команду: Extract CSS classes from HTML;
- Вставить полученное куда необходимо (CSS/LESS/SASS).

Comment: Какая комбинация клавиш, чтобы вставить этот код в фаил css?

Comment: В командной строке я прописал npm install -g vsce. После этого у меня сработала комбинация Ctrl+V

Answer (score 1):

Плагин eCSStractor for VSCode)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]